# Bibliography name does not change

Tags: biblatex, xetex

I have the following MWE and the problem is that Bibliography title won't modify as intended to "Referencias."

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot,es-lcroman,es-noquoting]{babel} %Hyphen
    \addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand\contentsname{ÍNDICE GENERAL}}
    \addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand\listfigurename{ÍNDICE DE FIGURAS}}
    \addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\listtablename}{ÍNDICE DE TABLAS}}
    \addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}}
    \addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}}
    \addto\captionsspanish{%
        \renewcommand\appendixname{ANEXO}
        \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Anexos}
        }
    \addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\refname}{REFERENCIAS}}

\usepackage{wrapfig}                    %Texto alrededor de imágenes.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                   %Encabezado.
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}         %Referencias no aparece numerada
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}   %Simple modificacion apendices
\renewcommand{\addappheadtotoc}{%
  \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\appendixtocname}%
}
\usepackage{float}                      %Posiciona figuras en lugar deseado.
    \setlength{\intextsep}{10pt}                %Float environment spacing before and after.
\usepackage{etoolbox}                   %For Appendix page number A.1...D.1
\usepackage{tocloft}
    \renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip1pt}
    \renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip2pt}
    \renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip2pt}
    \setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{2pt}
    \setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{1pt}
    \renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\Large \bfseries}
    \renewcommand\cftlottitlefont{\Large \bfseries}
    \renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\Large \bfseries}
    \setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0em}
    \setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{0em}
    \setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{0em}
    \setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{1.5em}
    \setlength{\cftafterlottitleskip}{1.5em}
    \setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{1.5em}
    \cftsetindents{figure}{0em}{3.3em}
    \cftsetindents{table}{0em}{3.3em}

%%% Patching the kernel \@sect command
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\@sect}{\fi#7}{\fi\@nameuse{format#1}{#7}}{}{}

%%% for sections and subsections we want uppercase
\protected\def\formatsection{\MakeUppercase}
\protected\def\formatsubsection{\MakeUppercase}

%%% the other titles are left unchanged
\let\formatsubsubsection\@firstofone
\let\formatparagraph\@firstofone
\let\formatsubparagraph\@firstofone

%%% the following is necessary only if hyperref is used
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
    \let\formatsection\@firstofone
    \let\formatsubsection\@firstofone
  }%
}
\makeatother
%\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
%\newcommand{\appendixpagenumbering}{
%  \break
%  \pagenumbering{arabic}
%  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thechapter-\arabic{page}}}
\usepackage{amsmath}             %To write equations and math symbols.
    \let\hbar\relax              %Conflicting issue with fontspec and mtpro2.
\usepackage[mtpcal,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo,amssymbols]{mtpro2} %MathTime Professional 2 for fluency with Times font and Times math.
\usepackage{mathtools}           %For equation with cases.
\usepackage{siunitx}             %For SI units
\usepackage{caption}             %All lines left aligned.
    \captionsetup{format=hang}
\usepackage[bibstyle=apa,citestyle=authoryear-comp,maxcitenames=2,uniquelist=false,giveninits=true,uniquename=init,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,dashed=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
    \DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}
    \AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    %\addbibresource{R.bib}
    \DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{%
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
    }
    \DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyearpar}     %Use hyperef with citeryearpar command.
    {}
    {\mkbibparens{\bibhyperref{\printdate}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}
    \DefineBibliographyExtras{spanish}{\protected\def\bibrangedash{\textendash}}
\usepackage{rotating, booktabs}           %Better hline commands.
\usepackage{enumitem}                 %Spacing in list items.
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\circ$}
\usepackage{scrextend}                %Margin indentation.
\usepackage{multicol,multirow}        %Can make cells in tables with multiple rows or columns.
\usepackage{sectsty}                  %Hooks to change section header styles.
    \sectionfont{\normalsize}
    \subsectionfont{\normalsize}
    %\paragraphfont{\small \MakeUppercase}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{chngcntr}               %Per-section numbering in article class.
    \counterwithin{figure}{section}
    \counterwithin{table}{section}
    \counterwithin{equation}{section}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}            %Footnotes in table environments

\usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]   
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{1em}{}   
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-15pt}{25pt}

\setlength\parindent{0.5in}           %Paragraph indentation.

\captionsetup{belowskip=1pt,aboveskip=4pt}

\usepackage[bookmarks,hypertexnames=false,debug]{hyperref}

\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in,footskip=1.2cm,headheight=2cm,headsep=0.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}                 %Encabezado.
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}                            % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{Some graphics}
\fancyhead[LE]{{\small \textsc{Uni}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{{\small \textsc{Dep}}}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\small \thepage}
\fancyfoot[RO]{{\footnotesize \MakeLowercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyfoot[LE]{{\footnotesize \MakeLowercase{\rightmark}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{               %  the preset of fancyhdr 
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LO]{Some graphic}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\textsc{Uni\\Dep}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\small \thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}}

\usepackage[spanish,tight]{minitoc}          %Table of Contents per Chapter
%\addto{\captionsspanish}{\renewcommand{\mtctitle}{Another Title}}

\usepackage{bookmark}
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=black}

\usepackage{fontspec}                   %Set a main font.
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}[SmallCapsFont=TeX Gyre Termes,SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}]

\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}          %Fancy pantsy ref.
    \Crefname{section}{Sección}{Secciones}
    \Crefname{chapter}{Capítulo}{Capítulos}
    \Crefname{table}{Tabla}{Tablas}
    \Crefname{app}{Anexo}{Anexos}
    \Crefname{graph}{Gráfico}{Gráficos}

%Hyphenation not included
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    p_{\textrm{f}}=\Phi (-\beta)
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Please help.

Comment: You could add `bibliography = {REFERENCIAS}` to `\DefineBibliographyStrings`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `book` (and `report`)-like classes `biblatex` (and indeed `thebibliography`) use `\bibname` and not `\refname` as bibliography heading. So you would need to redefine `\bibname` and not `\refname`.

If you load `biblatex`, `biblatex` takes over control over `\bibname` and `\refname` and so it is easier to use its interfaces to control the values of these commands than a meticulously-timed

```
\AtEndPreamble{\appto\extrasspanish{\renewcommand*{\bibname}{REFERENCIAS}}}
```

to counter `biblatex`. This would be done by redefining the `bibliography` bibstring in `\DefineBibliographyStrings`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot,es-lcroman,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{
  bibliography = {REFERENCIAS},
}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The image shows parts of the last page of the example document. The heading for the bibliography is REFERENCIAS in all caps.]